# How to convert BMP to PNG (or JPEG) without deterioration?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap

I want to convert Bitmap image to PNG without deterioration. I was trying to use code below. It works, but there is a big difference in image's colour after converting (look at attached image). What is the cause of this?

The resolution of this image is 30px * 30px. (Sizes of images before processing and after processing are different, but the actual number of pixels is the same)

```
        val bitmap = (any bitmap image)
        val fos = FileOutputStream(saveDir)
        var newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, bitmap.config)
        var canvas = Canvas(newBitmap)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
        newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
```

Before (Bitmap)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhSoZ.jpg

After (PNG)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzpvo.jpg

Comment: What are you messing around with a new bitmap? Why not simply `bitmap.compress()` ?

Comment: `The size of the image is different between the before and after images, ` It is pretty unclear what you consider to be the size of an image.

Comment: can you tell the value of bitmap.config?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
The reason why is alpha value of bitmap.
I made this original icon image by AndroidAssetStudio.
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

the image I made had alpha value, therefore I didn't realized it hided true icon color. it was not red color like #FF0000. So its color didn't chang as I expected.

I deleted alpha value by changed extension from bmp to jpeg bmp for original image before I use bitmap.compress. And then it worked.

Thank you for your answer.